# no-op if statement causes google charts to fail?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

how can a javascript `if` statement cause this?
The body of the `if` statement is always executed, but it seems the mere presence of the `if` statement causes google charts not to work properly...

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
...
...
...

var chart1 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chartId1'));
var chart2 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chartId2'));
...

var drawCharts = function() {
  var chart1Width = jQuery('#chartId1').width();
  var chart2Width = jQuery('#chartId2').width();
  ...

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  var chartOptions = {...};

  data.addColumn(...);
  data.addColumn(...);
  data.addRows([...]);
  chart1.draw(data,chartOptions);
  console.log('chart 1 drawn');

  //if I uncomment the next line the chart is not drawn
  //if (chart2Width > 80) {
  data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn(...);
  data.addColumn(...);
  data.addRows([...]);
  chart2.draw(data,chartOptions);
  console.log('chart 2 drawn');
  //if I uncomment the next line the chart is not drawn
  //} else {console.log('chart 2 not drawn');}
};
drawCharts();
jQuery(...).bind(...., function() {drawCharts();});
```

additionally only when add the if statement do I get numerous exceptions from the `chart2.draw(...);` line: `Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cy="NaN"`, `Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="MNaN,NaNL226,NaNL226,1.5L409.5,1.5"`, `Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="MNaN,NaNL206,NaNL206,1.5L22.5,1.5"`, etc...

since `console.log('chart 2 drawn');` happens in either scenario this would mean that the `if` statement should have no effect... yet the chart doesn't display and I get exceptions...

how can a javascript `if` statement cause this?

Comment: So when you put in you if statement it does not work and when not it works properly?

Comment: What's the value of `chart2Width` right before the if statement?

Comment: @BrianShamblen `chart2Width` is like 250+   though as the page loads and depending on if the chart is hidden it can be 25 or less.  I also tried redeclaring `chart2` just before drawing with the same results

Comment: @Mikey chart2 works fine if it is showing but the 4 other hidden charts result in dozens of errors each on each attempt to draw, the error is because the chart is not visible and has a "width" less than 25 and google renders svg with negative lengths... so I assumed if I tried to prevent it by doinging a width check that would prevent drawing while the chart was hidden, but instead it causes it not to work while visible, thus making things much worse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of the issue by forcing the height of the graph container before an attempt to draw...

```
if (chart2Width > 80) {
  jQuery('#chartId2').height(chart2Width/2);
  data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn(...);
  data.addColumn(...);
  data.addRows([...]);
  chart2.draw(data,chartOptions);
  console.log('chart 2 drawn');
} else {
  console.log('chart 2 not drawn');
}
```

apparently the `chartArea.height` configuration option doesn't work as expected...

still don't know why rendering the graph while not visible would result in ignore-able errors but yet those errors are required to allow it to work when it does become visible if the height is not explicitly set...